# Is it possible to have more than one recovery installed in android?If How do i find if what recovery someone is using?

Tags: android

Currently, I am making an Android app which require `Root privileges`. Basically what it does is that it flashes a zip file via recovery[Custom Recovery's like TWRP,CWM]. The problem is that I don't know whether multiple Recovery's can be set up like Multi Rom on the same device. And if possible how do I find list of `Recovery's` that is installed on the `device`.